# FCM was working minutes ago, but now says "InternalServerError"

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

My code was working just great, but then I started having "InternalServerError" in the response payload.

Here's my Javascript:

```
var notifBody = "XYZ accepted your invitation";

              // FCM payload
              var payload = {
                to: token, 
                content_available: true,
                sound : "default",
                priority: "high",
                notification : {
                  body: notifBody,
                  title: "K,",
                  badge : "1"
                }, 
                data: {
                  inviteId: pThis.identifier
                }
              };

              var serverKey = "#serverkeygoeshere";
              var data = JSON.stringify(payload);
              $.ajax({
                url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "key="+serverKey,   
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.info(data);
                }
            });
```

The response I get: 
{"multicast_id":4805899833962074421,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InternalServerError"}]

Any clue?

Comment: Sounds like the receiving server has an internal error?

Comment: same problem without reason